# Saving workbook with variable print scaling options

Tags: excel, vba

Long time reader but this is the first time that I come here to ask something, hopefully someone will be able to help me out with my problem!

I'm trying to save a workbook (with several sheets) into PDF file, the problem is that each of the sheets has a different print configuration!
Some practical examples:
Sheet 1 is scaled such as it should be "printed" as 1 page tall by 2 page wide
Sheet 2 is scaled such as it should be "printed" as 1 page tall by 3 page wide
Sheet 3 is scaled such as it is adjusted to 80% of normal size

If I manually try to save the spreadsheet as a pdf (using the print option) the output format is exactly how I want (because I already configured manually each sheet) but when I use the Export function in VBA everything comes messed up...

My current code is quite basic:

```
Dim strFileName As String
Dim strThisFolderPath As String
strThisFolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
strFileName = InputBox("Enter file name")
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
strThisFolderPath & strFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
False
End Sub
```

Does anyone know how I can set up the code in order to fix this?

Regards,
Luis

Comment: Have you tried just printing to PDF instead of exporting? Printing will use the settings as defined in each sheet.

Comment: I know you want all the pages in One file, but, are they still messed up if you export individual pages? I.e `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` etc.

Comment: @teylyn, That was my first attempt but I couldn't find any code that would use the print option to save the excel spreadsheet as pdf (and the SaveAs function doesn't allow the pdf format), this would definitely solve the problem though.

Comment: Guys!!! I managed to find the solution... for some reason the problem was related to the page scaling configuration in excel... I went to options -> Advanced -> General and unchecked the "Scale content for A4..." Thank you both for your support!